# AD Authentication (System Assigned Managed Identity) with Azure SQL Managed Instance not working?

Tags: spring-boot, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, azure-sql-database

I am trying to connect to the Azure SQL Database from App Service Spring boot application with System managed identity. I am trying to connect to the database using ActiveDirectoryMSI and MSIClientId. In my database I have the connection string for SQL Authentication, AD Password Authentication, AD Integrated Authentication. App service MI is added as a user to the database with roles as dbreader and dbwriter. While deploying the application I am getting the error as

**com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot set AccessToken property if "Authentication" has been specified in the connection string.**

I am trying to get the token for my database here.

Can someone help how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

> accessToken can only be set using the Properties parameter of the
> getConnection() method in the DriverManager class. It can't be used in
> the connection string.

Based on the error it is telling you that you specified "**AccessToken**" property in part of your Connection String, but the documentation specifically tells you to not do that.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/connecting-using-azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver15

---

**accessToken**:

> Use this connection property to connect to a SQL Database with access
> token. accessToken can only be set using the Properties parameter of
> the getConnection() method in the DriverManager class. It can't be
> used in the connection URL.

Example:

```
public class AADTokenBased {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // Retrieve the access token from the AD.
        String spn = "https://database.windows.net/";
        String stsurl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/..."; // Replace with your STS URL.
        String clientId = "1846943b-ad04-4808-aa13-4702d908b5c1"; // Replace with your client ID.
        String clientSecret = "..."; // Replace with your client secret.

        String scope = spn +  "/.default";
        Set<String> scopes = new HashSet<>();
        scopes.add(scope);

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        IClientCredential credential = ClientCredentialFactory.createFromSecret(clientSecret);
        ConfidentialClientApplication clientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplication
            .builder(clientId, credential).executorService(executorService).authority(stsurl).build();
        CompletableFuture<IAuthenticationResult> future = clientApplication
            .acquireToken(ClientCredentialParameters.builder(scopes).build());

        IAuthenticationResult authenticationResult = future.get();
        String accessToken = authenticationResult.accessToken();

        System.out.println("Access Token: " + accessToken);

        // Connect with the access token.
        SQLServerDataSource ds = new SQLServerDataSource();

        ds.setServerName("aad-managed-demo.database.windows.net"); // Replace with your server name.
        ds.setDatabaseName("demo"); // Replace with your database name.
        ds.setAccessToken(accessToken);

        try (Connection connection = ds.getConnection();
                Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT SUSER_SNAME()")) {
            if (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println("You have successfully logged on as: " + rs.getString(1));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not using any client secret for my project.

Comment: I am trying for using activedirectorymsi auth method. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/connecting-using-azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver15#connect-using-activedirectorymsi-authentication-mode I get the MSI token failure. I was confused before for trying out lot of things and mixed the accessToken with activedirectory msi. Its clear with the link you provided that I need to use MSI for auth for Managed Identities. Can you help with this?